# Sum worked hours

Tags: sql-server

I have a issues table where users can log worked hours and estimate hours that looks like this

```
id |  assignee  |  task   |   timespent  |  original_estimate | date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |  john      |  design |   2          |  3                 | 2013-01-01
2  |  john      |  mockup |   2          |  3                 | 2013-01-02
3  |  john      |  design |   2          |  3                 | 2013-01-01
4  |  rick      |  mockup |   5          |  4                 | 2013-01-04
```

And I need to sum and group the worked and estimated hours  by task and date to get this

```
assignee  |  task   | total_spent   | total_estimate  |  date
------------------------------------------------------------------
john      |  design | 4             | 6               | 2013-01-01
john      |  mockup | 2             | 3               | 2013-01-02
rick      |  design | 5             | 4               | 2013-01-04
```

Ok, this is easy, I've already got this:

`SELECT assignee, task, SUM(timespent) as total_spent, SUM(original_estimate) AS total_estimate, date FROM issues GROUP BY assignee, task, date`

My problem is I need to also show the assignees that did not logged hours on any task that day, I mean:

```
assignee  |  task   | total_spent   | total_estimate  |  date
------------------------------------------------------------------
john      |  design | 4             | 6               | 2013-01-01
john      |  mockup | 2             | 3               | 2013-01-02
rick      |  design | 5             | 4               | 2013-01-04
pete      |  design | 0             | 0               | 2013-01-01
pete      |  mockup | 0             | 0               | 2013-01-02
liz       |  design | 0             | 0               | 2013-01-04
liz       |  mockup | 0             | 0               | 2013-01-04
```

The goal is to draw a chart like this http://jsfiddle.net/uUjst/embedded/result/

Comment: You need a RIGHT JOIN, so that users without log records for the day aren't excluded.

Comment: Can you explain why pete gets a row for both design and mockup but liz only gets a row for design? Where do these additional names come from?

Comment: @RobertHarvey that was my instinct too, but looks like he isn't using any joins, just one table. I think, in fact, that he's trying to do fabricate rows from one table. OP, that's not possible. If that's not what you're trying to do, explain yourself better.

Comment: Have you 'assignee' table?

Comment: ok, yes the names come frome another table lets say users table, I would do a right join, that would leave me with the task name and date with null values

Comment: Still doesn't explain why you want two rows for Pete and one row for Liz. Can you post some sample data for the users table so we know how you're deciding on the output you want?

Comment: Ok, with the updated data... why do liz and pete show 0 hours on 2013-1-04... but not on any of the other days?  Shouldn't they show 0 hours on all days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `user` table, but not a `tasks` or `dates` table... meaning that we have to derive these values from the values present in `issues`:

```
;WITH dates AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT date
    FROM issues
), tasks AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT task
    FROM issues
)
SELECT 
    u.user as assignee, 
    t.task, 
    SUM(i.timespent) as total_spent, 
    SUM(i.original_estimate) AS total_estimate, 
    d.date 
FROM 
    users u CROSS JOIN
    dates d CROSS JOIN
    tasks t LEFT OUTER JOIN
    issues i ON
        i.assignee = u.user
        AND i.task = t.task
        AND i.date = d.date
GROUP BY u.user, t.task, d.date
```

Comment: Yes this is sort of my scenario! I'm testing your answer

Answer (score 1):

You need the Assignees in their own separate table to join from.

```
SELECT  tblAssignee.Name, task, SUM(timespent) as total_spent, SUM(original_estimate) AS   total_estimate, date 
FROM tblAssignee
    LEFT JOIN issue ON issues.assignee = tblAssignee.Name
GROUP BY tblAssignee.Name, task, date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   A.name,
   task,
    ISNULL(SUM(timespent), 0) as total_spent,
    ISNULL(SUM(original_estimate), 0) AS total_estimate,
    date
FROM Assignee A
    LEFT JOIN issue
        ON issues.assignee = A.Name
GROUP BY A.name, task, date
```